# subsetting a csv file in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file like this example:

```
Name,SampleProbe
IRF2,231.14
IRF2,340.19
IRF2,139.57
PTEN,115.57
PTEN,240.4
PTEN,117.92
PRKACB,180.02
PRKACB,396.13
PRKACB,186.9
```

As you see every item in the first column is repeated 3 times and consequently for every item I have 3 values in the 2nd column. I am trying to make a sebset of this file (as a pandas dataframe) in which the first column is IRF2 and PTEN like expected results:

Expected results:

```
IRF2    231.14
IRF2    340.19
IRF2    139.57
PTEN    115.57
PTEN    240.4
PTEN    117.92
```

to do so I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 10.0)
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = "serif"
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
df2 = df[[df['Name' == 'PTEN' AND 'Name' == 'IRF2']['SampleProbe']]]
```

It does not return the expected results. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @jezrael: this is not duplicate question

Comment: Can you explain why? because I think need `df2 = df.loc[df['Name'].isin([ 'PTEN' , 'IRF2'], 'SampleProbe']`

Comment: error:     File "<ipython-input-74-cde4f1b08a6a>", line 2
    df2 = df.loc[df['Name'].isin([ 'PTEN' , 'IRF2'], 'SampleProbe'])
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, forget for `)` - `df2 = df.loc[df['Name'].isin([ 'PTEN' , 'IRF2']), 'SampleProbe']`

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks. but the results still is not correct! not like expected results.

Comment: 0     231.14
1     340.19
2     139.57
3     242.62
4     245.84
5     165.40
6     249.31
7     305.07
8     114.75
9     289.28
10    237.61
11    131.64
12    115.57
13    240.40
14    117.92
15    391.46
16    267.12
17    155.31
18    302.73
19    249.34
20    119.64
21    333.32
22    402.38
23    139.52

Comment: I fixed that:  df2 = df.loc[df['Name'].isin([ 'PTEN' , 'IRF2']), ['Name', 'SampleProbe']]

Comment: `df2 = df[df['Name'].isin([ 'PTEN' , 'IRF2'])] `

Comment: @ jezrael:  I fixed that